# why does mysqli fetch create an infinite loop when in function?

Tags: php, function, mysqli

Why does this function return an infinite loop? I am trying to create a function where you just have to give it the query and the while loop takes care of the rest. but for some reason ONLY when i have the function return $q->fetch_assoc() it goes into an infinite loop. if I return just $q, then call $q->fetch_assoc() in the while loop then it doesn't cause the infinite loop.

```
public function fetch($query){
    $con = $this->con;
    $q = $con->query($query);

    return $q->fetch_assoc();
}

while($r = $sqli->fetch("SELECT id FROM users LIMIT 5")){
    echo $r['id']."<br />";
}
```

also tried

```
public function fetch($query){
    $con = $this->con;
    $q = $con->query($query);

    return $q->fetch_assoc();
}

$x = $sqli->fetch("SELECT id FROM users LIMIT 5");

while($r = $x){
    echo $r['id']."<br />";
}
```

I thought maybe it was recreating a new fetch function every time. This too did not work and caused the infinite loop.

Comment: `return $q->fetch_assoc();` only returns 1 row, and is not affected   by the `LIMIT 5`, so your function `fetch()` always returns `true`, so the `while($r = $sqli->fetch(...))` or `while($r = $x)` runs infinitely.

Comment: what should be the work around? I need to be able to give the function the query and only have to loop through it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you call the function you RE-RUN the query, which resets the data set to the first record.

e.g. You have 5 records that get returned:

```
function get() {
    .... run query
    return 1st record
}
```

You'll **NEVER** get records 2,3,4,5 because you keep resetting the query to the beginning.

Your function should be returning the result HANDLE:

```
function do_query($sql) {
    $result = $con->query($sql);
    return $result;
}

while($row = $result->fetchRow()) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: But shouldn't it work when the function is set to a variable outside the while loop?

Comment: Yes, but the loop in your second snippet is also wrong. You just keep assigning $x to $r, and as long as $x has a value this continues.

Comment: How so? The fetch_assoc() is assigned to the variable, therefore only running once. Where is it wrong?

Comment: Your second function does `$x = get_first_record()` then just keeps looping on $x, which will ALWAYS be true. Except for `fetchAll()`, fetch()-type functions only return **ONE** record from a result set.

Comment: thank you. I didn't know fetch only returned one record.

Answer (score 1):

`fetch` function has problem , when call this function reset query(reinitialize query) and fetching only first row without to indicate to next row.you have two way first way is use `query` function then use fetch function in while-loop.

```
public function query($sql){
    $con = $this->con;
    return $con->query($sql); // as result


}
public function fetch($result){

    return $result->fetch_assoc();
}
$query_r=this->query("SELECT id FROM users LIMIT 5"); // as result
while($r = $this->fetch($query_r)){
    echo $r['id']."<br />";
}
```

second way is smarter,use `key/value` query cache for save query(avoid reset/reinitliazing queries) and this way **closer to your `prototype`**

```
public $query_cache=array();
private function query($sql){
    $con = $this->con;
    return $con->query($sql); // as result


}
public function fetch($sql){
    $cache_item=@$this->query_cache[$sql];
    if(!$cache_item) { $cache_item=$this->query($sql);$this->query_cache[$sql]=$cache_item; }
    $row=$cache_item->fetch_assoc();
    if(!$row) unset($this->query_cache[$sql]);
    return $row;
}

while($r = $this->fetch("SELECT id FROM users LIMIT 5")){
    echo $r['id']."<br />";
}
```