# fetching a result from mysqli select query with limit via while returns infinite loop how to prevent this?

Tags: php, mysqli

somehow using `while()` to loop through `mysqli->fetch()` returns an infinite loop

I already set the `LIMIT 4` in query though. might be something wrong with the order of code I write

```
  <?php
  $user = $_SESSION['username'];

  $stmt=$con->prepare("SELECT id_msg,dari,subject,tgl 
  FROM inbox
  WHERE username=?
  ORDER BY id_msg DESC LIMIT 4");
  if($stmt===false){
     die("Error prepare ".htmlspecialchars($mysqli->error));
  }
  $bp=$stmt->bind_param("s",$user);
  if($bp===false){
     die("Error Binding param ".htmlspecialchars($mysqli->error));
  }
  $bp=$stmt->execute();
  if($bp===false){
      die("Error Execute ".htmlspecialchars($mysqli->error));
  }
  $bp=$stmt->bind_result($id,$dari,$subject,$tgl);
  if($bp===false){
      die("Error Bind result ".htmlspecialchars($mysqli->error));
  }
  $ambil=$stmt->fetch();

   while($ambil){
       echo $dari;
   } 
 ?>
```

Currently there's only 1 row in Inbox table, so it should only returns 1 result right....?

Comment: can't you just consult the manual http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php
`$ambil` will always be true thus making it infinite, what you're doing will continually fetch, instead, put it inside the while, it will terminate when all the rows are fetched

Comment: Please refer this http://stackoverflow.com/a/26019483/5635098

Comment: @Ghost yeah sorry.... I'll do that next time

Comment: Thank you @BachchaSingh, that's what I want to know, the reason

Answer (score 0):

I edited your code. Look at the end of script

```
<?php
 $user = $_SESSION['username'];

 $stmt=$con->prepare("SELECT id_msg,dari,subject,tgl 
 FROM inbox
 WHERE username=?
 ORDER BY id_msg DESC LIMIT 4");
 if($stmt===false){
    die("Error prepare ".htmlspecialchars($mysqli->error));
 }
 $bp=$stmt->bind_param("s",$user);
 if($bp===false){
     die("Error Binding param ".htmlspecialchars($mysqli->error));
 }
 $bp=$stmt->execute();
 if($bp===false){
     die("Error Execute ".htmlspecialchars($mysqli->error));
 }
 $bp=$stmt->bind_result($id,$dari,$subject,$tgl);
 if($bp===false){
     die("Error Bind result ".htmlspecialchars($mysqli->error));
 }
 $ambil=$stmt->fetch();

  while($ambil){
      echo $dari;

  // We need to get next result, else we will have infinite loop here
     $ambil=$stmt->fetch();
  // -----------------------------

  } 
?>
```

Comment: $stmt->fetch() will fetch only current row, then it will shift pointer to next result. If you need to get all result, you should call $stmt->fetch() in a loop